# What causes fruit taste enhancement?

Tags: biochemistry

I'm not sure if this is a biology or chemistry question, maybe both? Some fruits, such as quince and quondong, taste of nothing when raw but have an extremely strong flavour when cooked. Why?

Answer (score -1):

I am a little confused that does the word "cooked" means ripe？If yes, then the question will be easy to answer. Fruit has a kind of ripener, ethlyene. Ethlyene will help fructose break down and make up more glucose. That is why you may taste a strong flavour when fruit is cooked.

Comment: By cooking I mean literally heated with water in a saucepan. I'm not sure about glucose being the answer though. The 'flavour explosion' of cooked quince, in the mouth, seems to me to be far more than merely additional glucose.

Comment: So, when you cooked the quince (which means the quince got a higher temperature), the fructose would take a chemical reaction, polyreaction. And the fructose was transformed into amino acid. So you may taste sourer than before you cooked the quince. How do you think?